# Will 'going to' on public event in closed group show in news feed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline, facebook-privacy

I'm in a 'closed group' which has a 'public event'. I want to press 'going' on this event. I don't want it to appear on news feed/timeline (or whatever it's called) of my Facebook friends.

Will my friends on Facebook see that I'm going to this event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, event is Public and your activity will show to your friends with your action. It will show to your friends as you are going to that event.